# extract data from js shopping cart and send php email

Tags: javascript, php, shopping-cart

I am working on javascript shopping cart. Now i want to send cart details via Gmail to admin using php.
I am unable to extract data from shopping cart and compose it in message body of mail.
I know now to send emails.
I dont want to use database and i dont want to use sessions to manage my shopping cart.
Below is my code. Please help!

```
<body>
    <!-- Nav -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top bg-faded">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cart">Cart (<span class="total-count"></span>)</button><button class="clear-cart btn btn-danger">Clear Cart</button></div>
    </div>
</nav>


<!-- Main -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.azspagirls.com/files/2010/09/orange.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Orange</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Price: $0.5</p>
    <a href="#" data-name="Orange" data-price="0.5" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/vector_illustration_of_ripe_bananas_567893.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Banana</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Price: $1.22</p>
    <a href="#" data-name="Banana" data-price="1.22" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://3.imimg.com/data3/IC/JO/MY-9839190/organic-lemon-250x250.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Lemon</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Price: $5</p>
    <a href="#" data-name="Lemon" data-price="5" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

  
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="cart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cart</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="show-cart table">
          
        </table>
        <div>Total price: $<span class="total-cart"></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 


<script>
    // ************************************************
// Shopping Cart API
// ************************************************

var shoppingCart = (function() {
    // =============================
    // Private methods and propeties
    // =============================
    cart = [];
    
    // Constructor
    function Item(name, price, count) {
      this.name = name;
      this.price = price;
      this.count = count;
    }
    
    // Save cart
    function saveCart() {
      sessionStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    }
    
      // Load cart
    function loadCart() {
      cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
      loadCart();
    }
    
  
    // =============================
    // Public methods and propeties
    // =============================
    var obj = {};
    
    // Add to cart
    obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count) {
      for(var item in cart) {
        if(cart[item].name === name) {
          cart[item].count ++;
          saveCart();
          return;
        }
      }
      var item = new Item(name, price, count);
      cart.push(item);
      saveCart();
    }
    // Set count from item
    obj.setCountForItem = function(name, count) {
      for(var i in cart) {
        if (cart[i].name === name) {
          cart[i].count = count;
          break;
        }
      }
    };
    // Remove item from cart
    obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
        for(var item in cart) {
          if(cart[item].name === name) {
            cart[item].count --;
            if(cart[item].count === 0) {
              cart.splice(item, 1);
            }
            break;
          }
      }
      saveCart();
    }
  
    // Remove all items from cart
    obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {
      for(var item in cart) {
        if(cart[item].name === name) {
          cart.splice(item, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
      saveCart();
    }
  
    // Clear cart
    obj.clearCart = function() {
      cart = [];
      saveCart();
    }
  
    // Count cart 
    obj.totalCount = function() {
      var totalCount = 0;
      for(var item in cart) {
        totalCount += cart[item].count;
      }
      return totalCount;
    }
  
    // Total cart
    obj.totalCart = function() {
      var totalCart = 0;
      for(var item in cart) {
        totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
      }
      return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
    }
  
    // List cart
    obj.listCart = function() {
      var cartCopy = [];
      for(i in cart) {
        item = cart[i];
        itemCopy = {};
        for(p in item) {
          itemCopy[p] = item[p];
  
        }
        itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
        cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
      }
      return cartCopy;
    }
  
    
    return obj;
  })();
  
  $('.add-to-cart').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
    shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
    displayCart();
  });
  
  // Clear items
  $('.clear-cart').click(function() {
    shoppingCart.clearCart();
    displayCart();
  });
  
  
  function displayCart() {
    var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
    var output = "";
    for(var i in cartArray) {
      output += "<tr>"
        + "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" 
        + "<td>($" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>"
        + "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">-</button>"
        + "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
        + "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">+</button></div></td>"
        + "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">X</button></td>"
        + " = " 
        + "<td>$" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" 
        +  "</tr>";
    }
    $('.show-cart').html(output);
    $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
    $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
  }
  
  // Delete item button
  
  $('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
    var name = $(this).data('name')
    shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
    displayCart();
  })
  
  
  // -1
  $('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
    var name = $(this).data('name')
    shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
    displayCart();
  })
  // +1
  $('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
    var name = $(this).data('name')
    shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
    displayCart();
  })
  
  // Item count input
  $('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
     var name = $(this).data('name');
     var count = Number($(this).val());
    shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
    displayCart();
  });
  
  displayCart();
  
</script>
</body>
```

I

Answer (score 0):

Just from reading quickly your code it seems to me that you need to change:

```
function displayCart() {
    var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
    ...
```

with:

```
function displayCart() {
    var cartArray = sessionStorage("shoppingCart").listCart();
...
```

I did not try anything so maybe I'm missing the point, in which case I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Send the email with javascript using the funtion or what ever controlls the name,icon,and price,with the details(You need to add that 2) But the only thing l recommend dont use php for this because its gonna be hard you need to add a whole lot of code....If this didnt help sorry,lm not good with javascript.

UPDATE!!!
you cant send direct emails with javascript ;( Dont use php for this just make a simple admin panel and add funtions so when the buy was clicked it will send the funtion which you added with javascript so this will make everything super easy,and dont add a login to the admin panel just make a private domain to that domain and make it like something long like /products/admin/adminpanel/admin/registers/product/productview@siteadmins123

Or ldk just make a login page with really simple code because 99.9% are dont gonna think abou it